# T-SQL get all records after a certain date as well as a fixed number before in one query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sample data table:

```
eventDate           eventText
------------------- ----------
2018-05-01 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-02 13:00:00 Some event
2018-05-03 11:00:00 Some event
2018-05-04 11:00:00 Some event
2018-05-05 15:00:00 Some event
2018-05-06 14:00:00 Some event
2018-05-07 17:00:00 Some event
2018-05-08 16:00:00 Some event
2018-05-09 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-10 11:00:00 Some event
```

I want to retrieve ALL records after a certain date, but ALSO records prior to that date up to a certain maximum number of records.

So for example, let's say I'm asking for all records on or after 2018-05-05.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE eventDate >= '2018-05-05' ORDER BY eventDate

eventDate           eventText
------------------- ----------
2018-05-05 15:00:00 Some event
2018-05-06 14:00:00 Some event
2018-05-07 17:00:00 Some event
2018-05-08 16:00:00 Some event
2018-05-09 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-10 11:00:00 Some event
```

But now I want to include, *in the same query result*, a maximum of two records that are before the date 2018-05-05. So:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE eventDate >= '2018-05-05' ORDER BY eventDate -- pseudocode "AND OR eventDate < 2018-05-05 WITH MAXIMUM EXTRA RECORDS 2

eventDate           eventText
------------------- ----------
2018-05-03 11:00:00 Some event
2018-05-04 11:00:00 Some event
2018-05-05 15:00:00 Some event
2018-05-06 14:00:00 Some event
2018-05-07 17:00:00 Some event
2018-05-08 16:00:00 Some event
2018-05-09 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-10 11:00:00 Some event
```

The maximum records is a maximum, so if there are not enough entries that's OK and should not be an error:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE eventDate >= '2018-05-02' ORDER BY eventDate -- pseudocode "AND OR eventDate < 2018-05-02 WITH MAXIMUM EXTRA RECORDS 10

eventDate           eventText
------------------- ----------
2018-05-01 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-02 13:00:00 Some event
2018-05-03 11:00:00 Some event
2018-05-04 11:00:00 Some event
2018-05-05 15:00:00 Some event
2018-05-06 14:00:00 Some event
2018-05-07 17:00:00 Some event
2018-05-08 16:00:00 Some event
2018-05-09 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-10 11:00:00 Some event
```

I also want it to be valid if no records match the initial condition; in that instance return only two records:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE eventDate >= '2018-06-30' ORDER BY eventDate -- pseudocode "AND OR eventDate < 2018-06-30 WITH MAXIMUM EXTRA RECORDS 2

eventDate           eventText
------------------- ----------
2018-05-09 12:00:00 Some event
2018-05-10 11:00:00 Some event
```

Can I do this in a single query?

Also preferably would like to do this without a stored procedure or function if possible.

The use case is an API that will return "a list of all current and future records, including the most recent two prior records before current time"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ((SELECT t.*
       FROM myTable t
       WHERE eventDate >= '2018-05-05'
       ORDER BY eventDate
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP (2) t.*
       FROM myTable t
       WHERE eventDate < '2018-05-05'
       ORDER BY eventDate DESC
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY eventDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the check to Gordon

But is can be a little simpler:

```
declare @dt datetime = '2018-06-30'

SELECT t.*
FROM (   SELECT t.*
         FROM myTable t
         WHERE eventDate >= @dt
       UNION ALL
       ( SELECT TOP(2) t.*
         FROM myTable t
         WHERE eventDate < @dt
         ORDER BY eventDate DESC
       )
     ) t
ORDER BY t.eventDate;
```